# angularJS unit testing where run contains a HTTP request?

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and am trying to learn some best practices. I have things working, but would like to start adding some unit tests to my modules and controllers. The first one I am looking to tackle is my AuthModule.

I have an AuthModule. This Module registers a Factory called "AuthModule" and exposes things like "setAuthenticatedUser" and also fields like "isLoggedIn" and "currentUser". I think this is a fairly common pattern in an AngularJS application, with some variations on the specific implementation details.

authModule.factory(
    'AuthModule',
    function(APIService, $rootScope) {

```
  var _currentUser = null;
  var _isLoggedIn = false;

  return {
    'setAuthenticatedUser' : function(currentUser) {

      _currentUser = currentUser;
      _isLoggedIn = currentUser == null ? false : true;

      $rootScope.$broadcast('event:authenticatedUserChanged',
          _currentUser);

      if (_isLoggedIn == false) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:loginRequired')
      }

      $rootScope.authenticatedUser = _currentUser;
      $rootScope.isLoggedIn = _isLoggedIn;

    },
    'isLoggedIn' : _isLoggedIn,
    'currentUser' : _currentUser
  }
});
```

The module does some other things like register a handler for the event "loginRequired" to send the person back to the home screen. These events are raised by the AuthModule factory.

```
authModule.run(function($rootScope, $log, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("event:loginRequired", function(event, data) {
    $log.info("sending him home. Login is required");
    $location.path("/");
  });
});
```

Finally, the module has a run block which will use an API service I have to determine the current logged in user form the backend.

```
 authModule.run(
     function(APIService, $log, AuthModule) {
       APIService.keepAlive().then(function(currentUser) {
         AuthModule.setAuthenticatedUser(currentUser.user);
       }, function(response) { 
         AuthModule.setAuthenticatedUser(null);
       });
     });
```

Here are some of my questions:

My question is how would you setup tests for this? I would think that I would need to Mock out the APIService? I'm having a hard time because I keep getting unexpected POST request to my /keepalive function (called within APIService.keepAlive())?

Is there any way to use $httpBackend in order to return the right response to the actual KeepAlive call? This would prevent me from having to mock-out the API service?

Should I pull the .run() block out which obtains the current logged in user out of the AuthModule and put it into the main application? It seems no matter where I put the run() block, I can't seem to initialize the $httpbackend before I load the module?

Should the AuthModule even be its own module at all? or should I just use the main application module and register the factory there?

Answer (score 2):

Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the service have been configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.[angularjs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

I suggest you take a look at this [authentication service](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/), using a service is the way to go.

Hopefully this would help ... Good luck